# Ignite in Kubernetes has problems finding servers

Tags: caching, kubernetes, ignite

We are deploying a four-instance ignite cluster in kubernetes along with several micro-services that rely upon it. The servers host several caches, some of which are read-through and/or write-behind. Kubernetes service and clients are configured for discovery as directed in the Ignite documentation.

Often times on server startup at least one instance will never connect to the rest of the cluster, and that instance may need to be deleted and replaced multiple times before it joins.

Server instances may also end up segmenting out, sometimes two at a time, from the cluster for no recognizable reason. Kubernetes will replace those nodes with results similar to what happens on cluster startup.

Clients will also suddenly be unable to find a server instance and remain unable to connect to the cluster until the entire server cluster is restarted.

The cluster may run for days w/o issue, then suddenly server instances can't see each other, then clients can't find servers, and we spend a day bouncing everything over and over until it works. We have tried several changes to the kubernetes service, client and server configs, but we are unable to even diagnose, much less repair this issue.

We do suspect this is specific to kubernetes since a similar configuration was previously running fine in a VM-based environment w/o these issues.

Help appreciated.

Comment: can you provide log file from failed instance?

Comment: Not currently, but will update on next documented failure.

Comment: @CyrusK I don't have an answer yet, but [here is very similar report on Apache Ignite mailing list](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Unreasonable-segmentation-in-Kubernetes-on-one-node-reboot-td24102.html) and we're facing exact same issue (described in mailing list reply), either at start or during run-time Ignite cluster experiences segmentation and renders itself pretty much useless :( Let's join our forces in finding the solution by chatting in the mailing list and then post the answer (hopefully we'll find it) here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem using a GridGain Ignite cluster as Hibernate 2nd level cache within an Azure AKS Kubernetes cluster without being able to explain the problem.

The Ignite cluster works as expected for a few days, with applications joining the Ignite cluster even recovering from temporary network latency failures which are expected in the cloud, then unpredictably applications fail to join the Ignite cluster continuously and eventually the applications permanently fail to join the Ignite cluster.